# Spring Boot 2 Multiple Datasources initialize schema

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-boot, initialization

I have a Spring Boot 2 application that's using two datasources - one Oracle and one H2. The H2 datasource is set up as secondary, and I want to create the schema for it upon startup, but it never fires off the schema.sql file. This is my Data Source Config file:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties primaryDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return primaryDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.runlogdatasource")
    public DataSourceProperties runlogDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.runlogdatasource")
    public DataSource runlogDataSource() {
        return runlogDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }
}
```

This is my application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@my.database.com:1521/mydb
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=ENC(3PXcnoBndLpWN1EcMtmIn+odOwhdWjSrqANijutxuekKEIOco64Jew==)
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=never
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=60000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
jasypt.encryptor.bean=stringEncryptor
spring.runlogdatasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/runlogdb;CIPHER=AES;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;
spring.runlogdatasource.username=sa
spring.runlogdatasource.password=ENC(3PXcnoBndLpWN1EcMtmIn+odOwhdWjSrqANijutxuekKEIOco64Jew==)
spring.runlogdatasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.runlogdatasource.platform=h2
spring.runlogdatasource.schema=classpath:schema-h2.sql
```

For the primary datasource, I can see that it enters the DataSourceInitializerInvoker which is where it attempts to load up the schema, but since there are no schema-all.sql files it skips over that one. However, I do have a schema-h2.sql file, but for the secondary datasource it never enters the DataSourceInitializerInvoker and therefore never attempts to initialize the schema. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 18):

This is expected behaviour. When Primary datasource is specified only the schema and data for this datasource is executed. What you need to do in order to have this behavior is to define `DataSourceInitializer`for each of the two datasources.

```
        @Bean
        public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer1(@Qualifier("datasource1") DataSource datasource) {
            ResourceDatabasePopulator resourceDatabasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
            resourceDatabasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("schema-h22.sql"));
            resourceDatabasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("data-h22.sql"));

                DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
                dataSourceInitializer.setDataSource(datasource);
                dataSourceInitializer.setDatabasePopulator(resourceDatabasePopulator);
                return dataSourceInitializer;
        }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer2(@Qualifier("datasource2") DataSource datasource) {
        ResourceDatabasePopulator resourceDatabasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        resourceDatabasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("schema-h21.sql"));
        resourceDatabasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("data-h21.sql"));

            DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
            dataSourceInitializer.setDataSource(datasource);
            dataSourceInitializer.setDatabasePopulator(resourceDatabasePopulator);
            return dataSourceInitializer;
    }
```

You also need to disable the default spring data initialization. You can do this through `spring.datasource.initialization-mode=never`