# Its possible to load specific data.sql for each SpringbootTest annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have serveral `@SpringBootTest` tests,with an enbebbed database(h2) with a `data.sql` with the data for the tests. Each test has it's own domain and as the `data.sql` is growing large. I would like to know if there is any option to include a specific data.sql for each `@SpringBootTest` annotation, like de properties source.

I know there is a option, which is, create different `application.properties` and specify there the `data.sql` to load, but I would like to know if there are cleaner options.

Currently I have this:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MyApplication.class}, webEnvironment = 
SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class MyFunctionalTest {
```

And I would like something like this:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MyApplication.class}, webEnvironment = 
SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@H2Data("sepecific.sql)
public class MyFunctionalTest {
```

Comment: That is what the [`@Sql`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/jdbc/Sql.html) annotation is for.

Comment: I couldn't make it work with Junit5, all the examples that i saw were with Junit4.
Can you give an example of how is loaded in the @SpringBootTest? and with @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)

Comment: Doesn't matter what you use. Just add `@Sql` point it to the script you want to use ...

Answer (score 0):

Hi in my opinion it is possible I have done it for regular spring boot application  , I ave not tried it for Test but I am almost sure that it will work for test. You need to declare multiple `DataSourceInitializers` like I have done in this post:

```
@Bean
        public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer1(@Qualifier("datasource1") DataSource datasource) {
            ResourceDatabasePopulator resourceDatabasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
            resourceDatabasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("schema-h22.sql"));
            resourceDatabasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("data-h22.sql"));

                DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
                dataSourceInitializer.setDataSource(datasource);
                dataSourceInitializer.setDatabasePopulator(resourceDatabasePopulator);
                return dataSourceInitializer;
        }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer2(@Qualifier("datasource2") DataSource datasource) {
        ResourceDatabasePopulator resourceDatabasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        resourceDatabasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("schema-h21.sql"));
        resourceDatabasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("data-h21.sql"));

            DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
            dataSourceInitializer.setDataSource(datasource);
            dataSourceInitializer.setDatabasePopulator(resourceDatabasePopulator);
            return dataSourceInitializer;
    }
```

[Spring Boot 2 Multiple Datasources initialize schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51146269/spring-boot-2-multiple-datasources-initialize-schema/55378247#55378247)