# Load different schema.sql and data.sql for different datasources in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, datasource, database-schema

I have two datasources in my Spring Boot application. I want to initialize database at startup for local profile for both datasource with two different schema.sql and data.sql files. How to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot 2 Multiple Datasources initialize schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51146269/spring-boot-2-multiple-datasources-initialize-schema)

Answer (score 1):

According to the section [85.3 Initialize a Database](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/) of the documentation:

> Spring Boot can automatically create the schema (DDL scripts) of your DataSource and initialize it (DML scripts). It loads SQL from the standard root classpath locations: schema.sql and data.sql, respectively. In addition, Spring Boot processes the schema-${platform}.sql and data-${platform}.sql files (if present), where platform is the value of spring.datasource.platform. **This allows you to switch to database-specific scripts if necessary.** For example, you might choose to set it to the vendor name of the database (hsqldb, h2, oracle, mysql, postgresql, and so on).