# spring boot failed to run oracle plsql script

Tags: java, spring-boot, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to run schema.sql and data.sql file as per below code in spring boot application:

```
@Configuration
public class DataInitializerConfig {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("Datasource")
    private DataSource datasource;

    @Bean
    public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer() {
        Resource initSchema = new ClassPathResource("schema.sql");
        Resource initData = new ClassPathResource("data.sql");
        ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator(initSchema, initData);
        databasePopulator.setIgnoreFailedDrops(true);
        databasePopulator.setSeparator("**END OF FILE**");
        DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
        dataSourceInitializer.setDataSource(datasource);
        dataSourceInitializer.setDatabasePopulator(databasePopulator);
        return dataSourceInitializer;
    }
}
```

schema.sql and data.sql script seems to be fine as I can see no error while running here [fiddle for data and schema sql](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/961ae/39)

data.sql as below:

```
DECLARE id varchar(20);

BEGIN

select dbms_random.string('x',10) into id from dual;

INSERT INTO TABLE1 (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K)
select
     id ,
     dbms_random.string('x',255) ,
     dbms_random.string('x',255) ,
     dbms_random.string('x',10) ,
     dbms_random.string('x',5) ,
     sysdate + DBMS_RANDOM.value(0,86400)/86400 * 30 ,
     sysdate + DBMS_RANDOM.value(0,86400)/86400 * 30 ,
     sysdate + DBMS_RANDOM.value(0,86400)/86400 * 30 ,
     dbms_random.string('x',50),
     decode(round(dbms_random.value), 1, 'Y', 'N'),
     decode(round(dbms_random.value), 1, 'Y', 'N')
     FROM DUAL

connect by level <=10;

INSERT INTO TABLE2 (A,L,M,N)
select
     id ,
     trunc(dbms_random.value(0.01, 9999.99),2) ,
     sysdate + DBMS_RANDOM.value(0,86400)/86400 * 30 ,
     decode(round(dbms_random.value), 1, 'Y', 'N')
     FROM DUAL

connect by level <=10;

END;
**END OF FILE**
```

schema.sql as below :

```
DROP TABLE TABLE1;

DROP TABLE TABLE2;

CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (A VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, B VARCHAR(255), C VARCHAR(255),
D VARCHAR(10), E VARCHAR(5), F TIMESTAMP, G TIMESTAMP, H TIMESTAMP,
I VARCHAR(50), J VARCHAR(1), K VARCHAR(1));

CREATE TABLE TABLE2 (A VARCHAR(10), L DECIMAL, M TIMESTAMP, N VARCHAR(1));

**END OF FILE**
```

Tables are not created from schema.sql. Infact on debug I saw no lines are read.
I think problem is with schema.sql

**Please provide some pointer to solve this issue.**

Comment: Did you take a look at [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc). Spring boot should handle schema.sql without the need of explicitly reading it by yourself.

Comment: @Sajjad as suggested, i tried to use https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc     Still schema.sql not executed. My application is having multiple datasources. FYI

Comment: @Sajjad https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51146269/spring-boot-2-multiple-datasources-initialize-schema This tells that with primary datasource implicit behaviour will work while with secondary datasource, my way is recommended. Both my sql work if i remove setSeparator and anonymous plsql block. As I need random data so I have to put under plsql block.

Comment: As far as I understood, your immediate problem is that spring boot is not picking up your `sql` scripts. Probably first, trying with a single datasource to see if it works with a simpler version of your problem?

Comment: @Sajjad I used plsql block for schema as well as shown here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/961ae/62 and after that it worked. Issue was separator was defined as **END OF FILE** and I have to define this separator because data.sql was in plsql block while schema was normal sql queries. That's why issue came. As soon as i changed that also as plsql , issue got resolved